# Page Fault in a Non-Paged Area - Now RAM is missing

Tags: memory, bsod

There are plenty of Posts on here about the "Page Fault in a Non Paged Area" BSOD.  My computer rebooted from the error with 8GB of RAM missing! (only 24 showing in the POST rather than 32).

Is it a coincidence that 2 sticks seem to have gone missing (they work in pairs, right? or is that not significant?)

How can I determine which sticks are faulty - is there a diagostic tool that can tell me which ports have 'No RAM' in them?

The Mobo is an Asus P9X79 WS

Answer (score 3):

This looks like faulty memory which is not being recognized or that suddenly died while you were using the system (thus the BSOD).

Probably a hardware problem, thus MemTest86 won't help: can you try those modules on another machine, and other modules on the same machine?

Comment: Will MemTest do me any good, if the RAM isn't even recognized during POST? Surely MemTest can't test memory that, according to the system, doesn't exist?

Comment: Hmm... You have a point there. This looks like a deeper hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

CPU-Z - to check what RAM slot is "empty."

memtest - to check what RAM is faulty.